# How to implement Pattern Along Path for shape in SVG

Tags: svg

Is it possible to repeat the background in svg path based on the line orientation, like pattern along path in inkspace?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, Inkscape does its pattern along path with offline calculations in the editor - there is nothing built into SVG that helps with this.